# Will the following Python module work with django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
   import Image,tesseract,cv2
    import numpy as np
    import cgi, os, sys
    import sqlite3 as db
    import sqlite3 as db

    def codingd(num):
         ##Thre hold..................................................................
         im_gray = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)

         (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
         thresh = 90
         im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
         cv2.imwrite('bw_image1.jpg', im_bw)
         key = cv2.waitKey(0)

         #improve image..........................................................
         im = cv2.imread('bw_image1.jpg') 
         gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
         blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
         thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,1,1,19,4)

         contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
         h_list=[]
         for cnt in contours:
              [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
              if w*h>250:
                   h_list.append([x,y,w,h])
         #print h_list          
         ziped_list=zip(*h_list)
         x_list=list(ziped_list[0])
         dic=dict(zip(x_list,h_list))
         x_list.sort()
         i=0
         for x in x_list:
               [x,y,w,h]=dic[x]
               #cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),1)
               im3=im[y:y+h,x:x+w]
               cv2.imwrite('objects/pix%i.png'%i,im3)
               i+=1

               #cv2.imshow('bw_image1',im)
         cv2.imwrite('bw_image1.jpg',im)
         key = cv2.waitKey(0)

         #adding object............
         im0 = cv2.imread('objects/pix0.png',0)
         im1 = cv2.imread('objects/pix1.png',0)
         im2 = cv2.imread('objects/pix2.png',0)
         im3 = cv2.imread('objects/pix3.png',0)
         im4 = cv2.imread('objects/pix4.png',0)
         im5 = cv2.imread('objects/pix5.png',0)

         h0, w0 = im0.shape[:2]
         h1, w1 = im1.shape[:2]
         h2, w2 = im2.shape[:2]
         h3, w3 = im3.shape[:2]
         h4, w4 = im4.shape[:2]
         h5, w5 = im5.shape[:2]
         maxh=max(h0,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5)

         #add 50 for space between the objects

         new = np.zeros((maxh, w0+w1+w2+w3+w4+w5+25),np.uint8)
         new=(255-new)
         new[maxh-h0:, :w0] = im0
         new[maxh-h1:, w0+5:w0+w1+5] = im1
         new[maxh-h2:, w0+w1+10:w0+w1+w2+10] = im2
         new[maxh-h3:, w0+w1+w2+15:w0+w1+w2+w3+15] = im3
         new[maxh-h4:, w0+w1+w2+w3+20:w0+w1+w2+w3+w4+20] = im4
         new[maxh-h5:, w0+w1+w2+w3+w4+25:] = im5
         gray = cv2.cvtColor(new, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)


         #cv2.imshow('norm',gray)
         cv2.imwrite('new_image1.jpg',gray)
         key = cv2.waitKey(0)

         # joom image 
         im = Image.open('new_image1.jpg')
         im2 = im.resize((70,35), Image.NEAREST)
         im2.save('new_image1.jpg')


         api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
         api.SetOutputName("outputName");
         #api.Init(".","eng")
         api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
         api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)
         mImgFile = "bw_image1.jpg"

         result = tesseract.ProcessPagesWrapper(mImgFile,api)
         return result
    mmmmmm= codingd(1)

sys.stdout.write("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("")
sys.stdout.write("<html><body>")
sys.stdout.write("<h2>Fahrenheit converted to Celsius</h2>")
sys.stdout.write("</body></html>")
```

I have created a simple function that convert image to text in python 2.7. Now I want to build a website that will help people to convert image to string object. Can any one tell me will those module work with django or how will I build that web app? As I am new to python I will appreciate detail information on this. I want that if I run a webpage then it will return the value of "mmmmmm" on the browser as string. above code is not working on browser but it compiled correctly on compiler.

Comment: Why not just check for yourself?

Comment: Declaring that "I've failed" is really not enough to make a good SO question. Please explain exactly what have you tried, how did you failed, what did you expect. Including relevant code samples, so other people could reproduce your problem. Otherwise this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I have edited the question and I am trying this from three weeks. above code is working on the python shell but when I create the local server and lode it with browser page stays blank @BartoszKP

Answer (score 0):

All python code I reused with Django works. The trouble is to insert it between HTTP request/responses. Example:

- You have a task which compute more than 2 seconds. A website doesn't use to deal this scale of time.

In this case, I suppose to you to use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or Web users will have to wait for tasks' end before get a response.

Comment: Can you tell me some reference to do that i am new to python @Zulu